# Por que não posso usar o || para ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
int i=0;
variable a;
a.type = CHAR;
a.name = malloc(sizeof(char)+1);
while(*l->str++ != ' ');
while(*l->str != ';' || *l->str != '='){
    a.name = realloc(a.name, ((!i)?1:i)*sizeof(char)+1);
    a.name[i] = *l->str;
    i++;
    *l->str++;
}
a.name[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", a.name);
```

Porem ele dá `segment fault`.

Quando retiro o `*l->str != '='` ou o `*l->str != ';'` da condição do `while` ele funciona normalmente. Gostaria de saber por que dá `segment fault` e se existe alguma forma sem `if` de se resolver.

Comment: O que é `l->str`? Onde está a declaração disso?

Comment: Faz tempo que não programo em C, qual a precedência dos operadores `||` e `!=`? Seria possível o compilador estar interpretando isso como `*l->str != (';' || *l->str) != '='`?

Comment: Acho que não, tenho quase certeza que o problema não é aí.

Comment: A condição `*l->str != ';' || *l->str != '='` sempre vai ser verdadeira. A única maneira dela ser falsa é se `*l->str` for `;` e `=` ao mesmo tempo. Obviamente, isso nunca vai acontecer. A mesma variável não pode ter dois valores diferentes.

Comment: @Havenard Creio que tem razão sobre a precedência. O problema está mesmo na condição.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me parece que seu problema é que seu `while` não tem condição de saída: ele vai continuar pra sempre! (ou melhor, vai continuar até dar um segfault) Suponha que sua string seja simplesmente:

```
;=
```

Usando `while(*l->str != ';')` o que acontece?

1. É diferente de `;`? Não. Então saia do loop.

Já usando `while(*l->str != '=')`:

1. É diferente de `=`? É. Vá para o próximo
2. É diferente de `=`? Não. Então saia do loop.

Mas usando `while(*l->str != ';' || *l->str != '=')`:

1. É diferente de `;`? Não, mas é diferente de `=`? É. Vá para o próximo
2. É diferente de `;`? É. Vá para o próximo
3. Segmentation fault

Ou seja, o problema está na sua condição. Veja se o que você quer na verdade não é um `&&`.

Comment: Cara, valeu, viajei com esse `||`.